# How to run a rails model in shell?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, shell

e.g. I have a model Student:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.do_something
    ss=Student.find_by_sex "m"
    ss.each do |s|
      s.blah
      s.save
    end
  end
end
```

I can do this:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.4)
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > Student.do_something
```

Now, I want a cronjob for this, How do I run above command without (rails c), so I can:

```
$ ruby student.rb
```

And get the same result? (I have gems: "mechanize", "hpricot", "to_lang" used in this model)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should take look at gem [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever). If you don't want to use it, you shoud try to use rails runner:

```
/great/path/to/my/application/script/rails runner "Student.do_something"
```